# Grails 2.5.4 + mongodb 5.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm trying to use plugin mongo 5.0.3.RELEASE with grails 2.5.4 and I'm getting the following error:

```
| Error 2016-03-22 12:58:25,956 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Could not find matching constructor for: org.grails.datastore.gorm.bootstrap.AbstractDatastoreInitializer(groovy.util.ConfigObject, java.util.ArrayList)
```

The exact same project works perfectly with mongodb 3.0.3 (after setting authSchema version to 3). The mongoDB version is v3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Check hibernate version you use. It might be 3.x. Mongodb 5.x requires hibernate4. More info: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/711

Answer (score -1):

Removing hibernate plugin resolved my problem